# How to set DHCP using connman for ethernet network

Tags: beagleboneblack, connman

I usually used connman to set static IP to my beaglebone hardware using below command:
`connmanctl config ethernet_985dad375f63_cable --ipv4 manual 192.168.1.101 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1`

How do I set beaglebone back to its dhcp configuration using 'connman' utility?

Comment: crazy stab in the dark: `connmanctl config ethernet_985dad375f63_cable --ipv4 dhcp`

Comment: Yes that is correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

Below command sets dhcp:
**connmanctl config ethernet_985dad375f63_cable --ipv4 dhcp**

Please note the numbers in 'ethernet_985dad375f63_cable' is my boards MAC. Replace it with your own board's MAC.